# How to make timestamp.txt file in R?

Tags: r

This is to get current time . I need to get something like 2021-02-08 12:33:04.txt file

```
library(lubridate)
    t <- Sys.time()
    cat(t,"\n")
    timeStamp <-  strftime(t,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    c<-as.character(str(as.POSIXlt(timeStamp)))
    writeLines(paste(timeStamp,"\n",user.str_input), "timeStamp.txt")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot write colons (`:`) in .txt file names.
One possible workaround is to eliminate colons from the file name, i.e.

```
writeLines('HELLO', paste0(gsub(':', '', timeStamp), '.txt'))
```

Comment: write.table("HELLO", paste0(gsub(':', '', timeStamp), '.txt')) as 
"x"
"1" "HELLO"

Comment: Did u test this ?

Comment: I've updated my answer because `write.table` tries to coerce the input object as matrix or dataframe. Now I'm using `writeLines` and I tested it, it should work.